# How to search for a file which name I don't know in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I know what's the directory which contains a file which name I don't know, but I know its name's ending (for example, .txt), also I know there's exactly one file with such ending in the directory.
I've tried the following code:`file=grep -w $1/*.txt` when $1 is the directory address which didn't help at all, neither did `file=$1/*.txt`.
Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the precise directory and a wildcard which will not match any other files, you could run a loop which loops only once.

```
for file in "$1"/*.txt; do
    : "$file" refers to your file here
done
```

Of course, in a lot of situations, you don't really need to know the precise file name.  If you want to run `grep` on the file which matches your wildcard, just do that:

```
grep "xyzzy" "$1"/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `find` command.

you can use it like this (make sure you're in the directory you would like to search):

`find . -iname '*.txt'`

use the command `man find` to learn more about the command.

Comment: or you can use "find dir_name -iname '*.txt'" where dir_name is the name of the directory to search in. That way you don't need to be in the directory

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/find directory_name -iname "*.txt"`

if you want to operate on those searched file you can even use with find -exec